# Delete the title of each chapter at the top. Book class

Tags: chapters, books

How can I eliminate the title of each chapter appearing at the top of the pages?

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
  text 1
 \newpage
  text 2
 \end{document}
```

[image]

**Actualization 1.**

With  `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}{ \markboth{}{}}` works but produces the following error:
[image]

Comment: Do you still want the page number in the header? If not then the easiest solution is to use `\pagestyle{plain}` that puts the page number centered in the footer, and nothing in the header.

Comment: Try this `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}{ \markboth{}{}}`.

Comment: @C.F.G I'd rather use `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{}{}}`. @eraldcoil Both solutions work but don't put the page number in the same place. Take your pick.

Comment: It worked for me but it produced an error. Attached photo on the subject.